# A or B or C query writing (Laravel blade)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having problem writing A or B or C query in Laravel blade file.
I wrote below code but these code just show up as html sentece. Could you teach me correct code please?

```
@if (Auth::user()->br_name == 'A' || Auth::user()->br_name == 'B' || Auth::user()->br_name == 'C' )
    @include('page.abc')
@endif
```

Comment: If Blade code shows up in your page most likely it isn't parsed by Blade. The most frequent cause for this is the file doesn't have a `.blade.php` extension.

Comment: Also maybe take a look into [in\_​array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)